# 360 image in cardboard app

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I have just purchased a 360 camera. I have seen on the cardboard demo app that you can view images in VR mode within the app. How do I go about doing this? I already know how to view a virtual environment from unity in VR mode but cant find a solution for doing it with 360 images.

Answer (score 2):

There is no out of the box support for this.

What you can do is the following:

- create a sphere
- place the 2 GC cameras inside the sphere
- use your image as the texture for the sphere

A few notes about this:

- the default sphere that comes with Unity is a UV [sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UV_mapping), you'll need an [icosphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icosahedron) to reduce the distortion near the pols.
- a sphere has the normals oriented outwards so you'll need to invert them so the rendering happens on the interior of the sphere instead of the outside